# Vue 3: Router.push change URL but doesn't load the page

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I'm trying to navigate from
`/checklist/1/item/2`
to
`/checklist/2/item/1`

with

`this.$router.push({ name: 'checklistitem', params: { id: this.id, aid: this.aid } });`

This changes the URL in browser, but doesn't load (render) the page with the new data.

The router is created with these

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import HomeView from '../views/HomeView.vue'

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: HomeView
  },
  {
    path: '/about',
    name: 'about',
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ '../views/AboutView.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/checklist/:id',
    name: 'checklist',
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ '../views/AcChecklistsView.vue'),
    props: true
  },
  {
    path: '/checklist/:id/item/:aid',
    name: 'checklistitem',
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ '../views/ChecklistView.vue'),
    props: true
  }
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  mode: 'history',
  routes
})

export default router
```

Has anyone an idea what's going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: If anything you should provide the content of `routes` which defines the actual routes and whether or not your router.push makes sense or should succeed.  It should tell us what component should be navigated to and if or what props we can expect Vue Router to update on the component.  Then, it would be necessary to see the component code.  If the route updates the route params and/or component props, do you have any code that is supposed to react to those changes?

Comment: If I understood correctly, shouldn't it be this.$router.push({ name: 'checklistitem', params: { id: this.id, aid: this.aid } });

Comment: Post also your ```App.vue```. Maybe there's no problem with the route but not triggering the view page.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it with adding `:key="$route.fullPath"` to `<router-view :key="$route.fullPath" />`